# Can not call a command

Tags: centos, init-script

I have a script `/etc/init.d/tilestream` with:

```
TILESTREAM="/usr/bin/tilestream"
MAPPATH="/data"
HOST="host"
#HOST="localhost"
#UIPORT="9001"
UIPORT="8888"
#TILEPORT="9000"
TILEPORT="8888"
SUBDOMAINS="a,b,c,d"

case $1 in
start)
    echo "Starting TileStream"
   $TILESTREAM --tiles=$MAPPATH --host=$HOST --uiPort=$UIPORT --tilePort=$TILEPORT&
    ;;
```

This works fine. But when I tried running it from the command line:

```
/usr/bin/tilestream --tiles=/data --host=host --uiPort=8888 --tilePort=8888
```

It didn't start; I couldn't see it in `top`. What can be wrong?

Comment: Is there any output on terminal? Is `localhost` defined in `/etc/hosts`? Try it with `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: In terminal i see `Started [Server Tile]`. I make a typo in command `host` needed not `localhost`. But it not help. Just can't understand why same command work in script but not in terminal.

Comment: That's not the entire script, what does the rest of it do? Are there any error messages? How exactly do you start it when it works? Do you just call `/etc/init.d/tilestream`? If you see `Started [Server Tile]` it sounds like it worked. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Can you try `pidof tilestream` instead of top?